# PHP SSH terminal inside Screen session

Tags: php, shell, libssh2

I'm trying to use libssh2 to send commands to connect to a Screen session on a CentOS box, (1) grab everything that's on the current page and then (2) allow the user to execute commands and grab the output of those commands.

I have explored a couple of approaches to get to this work, first by connecting the screen session and second by sending commands to the screen session.

For (1) I still have no idea how to do this. I'm looking for a Shell equivalent to print screen I guess, so that I can run the command inside PHP and grab the output and write it to the PHP output.

For (2) I've tried various permutations of the following:

```
screen -S `ls -1 /var/run/screen/S-root` -p 0 -X pwd
```

To try and run pwd inside a screen session (there is an assumption that there is only one running), but no output is returned, and when connecting to the screen session manually, I don't see my command run.

Comment: What you want to achieve at the higher level?

Comment: Pretty much a complete PHP SSH terminal inside a Screen session

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top

Scroll down to the bottom of that page to see a more salient example.